# How to use filter_if to select rows where any one of a number of logical variables in the data frame is true

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large data frame where rows are medicines with one or more component generic drugs. The DF has 21 logical variables indicating medicine contains one of a set of 21 generic drugs I want to filter for. Can I use filter_if to identify all the rows where any of these 21 variables is TRUE? Assuming I can, I think I am having trouble with the syntax for filter_if.

Here is my attempt so far and the error codes I'm getting. In the following code, the variables I am testing are in the columns"IBUPROFEN":"BAICALIN/CATECHIN" 
These are all logical TRUE/FALSE variables.

```
> Drug_Table_NamesNumberSML %>%
+   select("IBUPROFEN":"BAICALIN/CATECHIN") %>%
+   filter_if(isTRUE("IBUPROFEN":"BAICALIN/CATECHIN"))
```

Error in "IBUPROFEN":"BAICALIN/CATECHIN" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In isTRUE("IBUPROFEN":"BAICALIN/CATECHIN") : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In isTRUE("IBUPROFEN":"BAICALIN/CATECHIN") : NAs introduced by coercion

I dont understand where the NA/NaN argument error and the NAs introduced by coercion warnings are coming from.

I'm also not sure if this will do what I want it to do once those errors/warnings are addressed.

What I'd like to end up with is a data frame that contains only the rows that pertain to the 21 drugs for which I have logical variables to flag.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without a sample of your data to play around with (please provide some!), but I think `filter_all` could work.
If I understood correctly, something like this should give you what you want:

```
Drug_Table_NamesNumberSML %>%
    select("IBUPROFEN":"BAICALIN/CATECHIN") %>%
    filter_all(any_vars(. == TRUE))
```

You can find more examples of how to use different `filter` functions [here](https://suzan.rbind.io/2018/02/dplyr-tutorial-3/).